# Read custom headers passed in ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django, http, header

i am sending some custom headers to my view in django as below :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' },
        data: params,
        success:gi.payU.updatePaymentMethods
});
```

and i am getting it in request as below :

```
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://some_url/',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36',
 'HTTP_X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER': 'some value',  ## <-- my value
 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest',
```

What is the correct way to read this in django??

I tried multiple ways listed below but none seems to work :

```
(Pdb) request.COOKIES["HTTP_X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER"]
*** KeyError: 'HTTP_X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER'
(Pdb) request.X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER
*** AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER'
(Pdb) request.HTTP_X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER
*** AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'HTTP_X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER'
(Pdb) request.http_x-my-custom-header
*** AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'http_x'
(Pdb) request.HTTP_X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER
*** AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'HTTP_X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER'
(Pdb) request["HTTP_X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER"]
*** TypeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

and it works as below eventually :

```
request.META["HTTP_X_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER"] # note "HTTP_" append
```

**Question :**

lets say my varibale names are `a,b,c` do i need to *append* `http` to every variable to acces it?? like :

```
http_a
http_b
http_b
http_d
```

Is there any better way to access this where in i can directly access the variable name like we do to get `dict` values based on keys?

Comment: I'm don't think so. All the `X-*` are non standard headers and django's `request.META` dict contains standard http headers. This is django's way of identifying non-standard and standard headers. At least that's what it seems according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host). Although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about keys being prefixed with 'HTTP_'.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META), this is how Django builds the keys:

> With the exception of CONTENT_LENGTH and CONTENT_TYPE, as given above, any HTTP headers in the request are converted to META keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and adding an HTTP_ prefix to the name. So, for example, a header called X-Bender would be mapped to the META key HTTP_X_BENDER.

You can loop through all the headers and reverse this process to obtain the original header key.